# Conditional execution of activities

Tags: cadence-workflow

Does Cadence support conditional activities? My use case is a Workflow with multiple activities. Some activities have a condition that relies on the output of the preceding activities.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular question, using if condition in workflow code on activity result to decide next activity should work.